# How to stop iTerm2 closing tabs on error?

Tags: iterm

iTerm2 always closes the tab/window on error. By contrast, Terminal keeps it open so you can view the error.

How can I prevent iTerm2 from automatically closing the tab/window on error?

Comment: Thanks that helped. I fixed it by unchecking the setting under Preferences -> Profiles -> Session -> Automatically close a session when it ends

Comment: Glad I could help.  Even though it's a dupe, I up voted (to send you some reputation points) and hope that you leave the question here so there's another avenue for people to find the answer to this type of question.